# android 23 uri permission denial

Tags: uri, android-permissions

i have a code that doing the following:

1. i got READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest
2. i m getting photos uri from phone you choose and put it into fragment and insert into viewpager.
3. it works fine on sdk 22 below.
4. but as on android 23 it keep on saying

permission denial java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovioder.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord

which is refer to my code on line in fragment page

/*********************

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(uri), null, option);

which i put inside reSize() method

**********************/

5. i have trying to read develop console documents and notice we need to check permission and ask user for it.

my questions is 
1. which permission should i ask, i have tried READ and WRITE
2. where should i surround the check permission for, it is outside the method? or just surround the line.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            int hasPermission = checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        RESULT_PERMS_INITIAL);

            } else {

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(uri), null, option);
            }
        } else {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(uri), null, option);
        }
```

and on request for result

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == RESULT_PERMS_INITIAL) {

        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            bitmap = resizeBitmap(uri, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        }

        else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For API-23 Android introduced new permission types. You should read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

For the example please follow these page

- [RuntimePermissionsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/RuntimePermissionsBasic/index.html)
- [RuntimePermissions](https://developer.android.com/samples/RuntimePermissions/index.html)

I hope, it will work for you.